# How to attach Snake rig to curve modifer

Tags: animation

I'd like to animate a rigged snake character, using a curve modifier. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there an alternative option?
My aim is to make a smooth animation where the snake is flying/swirling in the sky while also being able to animate the rig.

[image: curve modifier]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the IK spline constraint on the bone at the end of the chain. I don't see exactly how this rig is made, so if you want to be able to deform the snake *off* of the curve, you might have to do some extra rigging, such as by making a chain of control bones to follow the curve, and parenting the bones that deform the snake to those.